# A question involving the concept of co-ordinate geometry.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

A line through origin meet the parallel lines 4x+2y=9 and 2x+y+6=0 at P,Q. Then the origin divides PQ in the ratio?

I tried using parametric form of equation but I feel the data is insufficient. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Just a similarity of triangles: $$\left|\frac{-9}{\sqrt{4^2+2^2}}\right|:\left|\frac{6}{\sqrt{2^2+1^2}}\right|=3:4$$

Comment: Great answer. Awesome 